# preg_match_all() into a simple indexed array rather than a multidimensional one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I run `preg_match_all()` like this:

```
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $array);
```

And it creates a multidimensional array like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(1, 2...)
);
```

But I want it to create a simple indexed array like:

```
$array = array(1, 2...);
```

`preg_match()` adds an indexed array, but somehow `preg_match_all()` has lost the very little that remained of its mind. Why? And what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
 preg_match_all($regex, $text, $array, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($output[0]);
 echo "</pre>";
```

You may wanna refer to this for further details: [preg_match_all into simple array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373600/preg-match-all-into-simple-array)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This still outputs a multidimensional array, please see: http://ideone.com/RAJ5rX

Comment: Just print_r $output[0] instead.